# Does Turing machine move left on particular input?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, decidability

We know that RE language is the collection of unrestricted grammar which is known as type-0 grammar that's why  emptiness, finiteness of every RE languages is undecidable. My question is how I check decidability "the Turing machine makes move left or not" on particular input string. I have found some internet contents but very difficult to understand. I want to understand just intuition which is brief, not the concrete proof.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4278289/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144821/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if we never move left? Either we halt at some time, or we always see the input $\sqcup$ (blank symbol) and choose to move right. But there is a finite number of states, and by the pigeonhole principle after a long time we will get stuck in a loop in those states.

Checking if we get stuck in a loop in the states, is not hard when the input is always $\sqcup$ - since we have to consider **only** the states.

---

In summary, the idea is to use the fact we will always see the same input after a while to our advantage - the states of a TM are finite, and hence it must act very simple (even simpler than a finite deterministic automaton!)